# Can I declare mappings in the persistence.xml?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I would like to declare in the persistence.xml file that every String type would be mapped to text type.
I want to declare the charset type too.

I woudn't like to declare this mapping by every single attribute with the @Column...

Answer (score 3):

There is no such 'default' configurations for datatypes. You would need to do set one by one.

If you want to do it in the persistence.xml you need to add a code like:

YOUR_PROVIDER

```
<!--
     create a file that will have the mapping,
     in this case the file name is orm.xml
-->
<mapping-file>orm.xml</mapping-file> 

<properties>
    <!--YOUR PROPERTIES-->
</properties>
```

Create a file with a code like the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
                 version="1.0">

    <entity class="com.uaihebert.model.test.Manufacturer">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="name">
                <!--Here you will declare your type-->
                <column  />
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```